# Asking user to allow push notifications after the sign up process

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

During the sign up process for my app I ask to allow push notifications, they press a "Allow Push notifications" button then I present the default prompt to allow push notifications.

The problem with this is that I am using parse.com as a backend and it requires me to save the device token when a users registers for push notifications. Since I am not asking them when the app launches I have no way of getting the device token and storing it to my Parse database.

If the user agrees to allow notifications, will the

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

method be called the next time they launch the app? If not, is there a way to get the device token anywhere else so that I can save it to Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` will be called as soon as the user allows them via the iOS notifications - wherever this is the execution of your application - in your case after the user logs in and agrees.  In this method you should take `[PFUser currentUser]` and put it into the `PFInstallation` object.

On subsequent launches of your application, if the user has requested notifications, you should once again call `registerForRemoteNotifications`, which will result in another call to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`, because the notification token may have changed.

If you allow the user to log out/in then you should update the `PFInstallation` object as appropriate.

Comment: i was registering for User notifications, not Remote notifications. I feel really dumb, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already implemented this method at your `AppDelegate`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

and

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Both callbacks are related to APNS request for device token.

After you registered your notification types, you should call `[application registerForRemoteNotifications]` to receive device token (or not) in respective callbacks above.

You are able to call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]` in any place to get the device token.